# File storing in website without changing URL

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, web, storage

Till now I have been storing my uploaded files in upload folder under the website folder. But now the Drive on which the site is stored is full. How do I store new files on another drive and how should I enter the Filepath in DB?

What I do.

1. Have a domain (eg. domain.com) point to a website folder
2. Upload files in upload folder under website folder
3. Store file path in DB as (/upload/filename)
4. retrieve file with base URL (www.domain.com/upload/filename)

Now if I store files on another drive how do I enter filepath in DB which would return me the file without affecting URL request.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HTTP handler.  There is no reason why the URL needs to be related to any physical location or resource.